# How to make android NDK work in windows?

Tags: android-ndk, windows-7-x64

I have downloaded android-ndk-r10e & I have also setted path in environment variable as well as NDK path for eclipse. I was able to build and run HelloJni sample app from eclipse, but when I use console to build it says

> 'ndk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

I have googled this and have also installed Cygwin even though it's not mentioned in offical google installation instructions(https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup.html) but to no vain.

I have set my path but when I do echo %path% it dosen't show up. How can I use NDK from command lines.[image]

Comment: You probably need to reboot or at least log off before Windows picks up the new %PATH%.

Comment: @Lennart log off didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're probably looking for is `ndk-build`, not `ndk`.